# issue in nice form select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used nice form for my web page. I have extracted the script from this website  http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jnice/. For select/menu if i type a letter in the drop down field, it doesn't jump to that letter. Default list/menu having that feature. But if i use nice form it doesn't work. How can i correct that?

This is the internal script that i have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $a = $('<a></a>');
        $('body').append($a);
        $a.click(function () {
            var element = $('#select2')[0];
            var myNewOption = new Option("My Option", "123", true);
            element.options[element.options.length] = myNewOption;
            $.jNice.SelectUpdate(element);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: here's a jsfiddle for you and others to use: http://jsfiddle.net/JJh9P/

Answer (score 0):

As it is you can't.

The plugin does not simply change the look and feel of forms element but emulates them by creating a completely different markup and behavior. If the behavior is not implemented, you won't get it. Besides the plugin seems to no longer be developed.

I suggest you to look for another similar, more achieved plugin like **[Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/#intro)** which will style the original select element, but still use it so you get all the defaul behavior, like typing a letter to jump to the first option...